# How can I set the selected item of the items in a filed into class in once query?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb-3.0

I want, that a person gets a list of requests with each selected offer owned by that person in once query (e.g. 'select * from Request r where r.selectedOffer = (select o from Offer r.offerList.owner = :owner(??)). Is it possible? Or I have to use two queries (one for request and one for offer), then I have to set a selected offer into request?

```
@Entity
public class Request() {

.....
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "requestId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<Offer> offerList = new HashSet<Offer>();

@Transient (or @OneToOne(mappedBy = "requestId"?? or another ways?)
private Offer selectedOffer;
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

```
 "FROM Request req JOIN req.offerList offer "+
      " WHERE req.selectedOffer.offerId = offer.offerId AND offer.owner = :owner"
```

Or I think simply this should do it:

```
 "FROM Request req WHERE req.selectedOffer.owner = :owner"
```

I am assuming `offerId` is primary key for `Offer` entity.

Comment: Which annotation should I use for selectedOffer?

Comment: @argonist `OneToOne` should be fine.